# XSLT for-each on xml

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, transform

this is my first question on stackoverflow.
I have an xml like this:

```
 <securityBasketDefinition>
    <securityBasketComponents>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityAlternateCodes/>
                <securityLabel>5536</securityLabel>
                <securityMarket>PT GOV</securityMarket>
                <securityDisplayLabel>PGB 3.85 15APR21</securityDisplayLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.022041737</weight>
            <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
            <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
            <componentType>bond</componentType>
        </securityBasketComponent>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityAlternateCodes/>
                <securityLabel>2941</securityLabel>
                <securityMarket>IT GOV</securityMarket>
                <securityDisplayLabel>BTP 3.75 1MAR21</securityDisplayLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.204042787</weight>
            <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
            <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
            <componentType>bond</componentType>
        </securityBasketComponent>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityAlternateCodes/>
                <securityLabel>5542</securityLabel>
                <securityMarket>FR GOV</securityMarket>
                <securityDisplayLabel>FRTR 3.75 25APR21</securityDisplayLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.228670367</weight>
            <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
            <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
            <componentType>bond</componentType>
        </securityBasketComponent>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityAlternateCodes/>
                <securityLabel>12897</securityLabel>
                <securityMarket>BE GOV</securityMarket>
                <securityDisplayLabel>BGB 3.000 28SEP19 - OLO67</securityDisplayLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.029298111</weight>
            <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
            <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
            <componentType>bond</componentType>
        </securityBasketComponent>
    </securityBasketComponents>
    <root>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>4905</label>
            <securityId>AT0000386115</securityId>
            <weight>0.039597771</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>2862</label>
            <securityId>AT0000A0VRF9</securityId>
            <weight>0.020257355</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>2867</label>
            <securityId>BE0000318270</securityId>
            <weight>0.053516328</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>12897</label>
            <securityId>BE0000327362</securityId>
            <weight>0.028389328</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>4848</label>
            <securityId>FI4000010848</securityId>
            <weight>0.019722759</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
    </root>
</securityBasketDefinition>
```

I need to match the label under tag /securityBasketDefinition/root/securityBasketComponentNew[X]/label with the tag /securityBasketDefinition/securityBasketComponents/securityBasketComponent[X]/securityId/securityLabel and than, when it's true, to update the tag under /securityBasketDefinition/securityBasketComponents/securityBasketComponent[X]/weight with the value of the /securityBasketDefinition/root/securityBasketComponentNew[X]/weight.

In this case the formula result should be this:

```
<securityBasketDefinition>
<securityBasketComponents>
    <securityBasketComponent>
        <securityId>
            <securityAlternateCodes/>
            <securityLabel>5536</securityLabel>
            <securityMarket>PT GOV</securityMarket>
            <securityDisplayLabel>PGB 3.85 15APR21</securityDisplayLabel>
        </securityId>
        <weight>0.022041737</weight>
        <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
        <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
        <componentType>bond</componentType>
    </securityBasketComponent>
    <securityBasketComponent>
        <securityId>
            <securityAlternateCodes/>
            <securityLabel>2941</securityLabel>
            <securityMarket>IT GOV</securityMarket>
            <securityDisplayLabel>BTP 3.75 1MAR21</securityDisplayLabel>
        </securityId>
        <weight>0.039597771</weight>   <== NEW VALUE
        <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
        <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
        <componentType>bond</componentType>
    </securityBasketComponent>
    <securityBasketComponent>
        <securityId>
            <securityAlternateCodes/>
            <securityLabel>5542</securityLabel>
            <securityMarket>FR GOV</securityMarket>
            <securityDisplayLabel>FRTR 3.75 25APR21</securityDisplayLabel>
        </securityId>
        <weight>0.228670367</weight>
        <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
        <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
        <componentType>bond</componentType>
    </securityBasketComponent>
    <securityBasketComponent>
        <securityId>
            <securityAlternateCodes/>
            <securityLabel>12897</securityLabel>
            <securityMarket>BE GOV</securityMarket>
            <securityDisplayLabel>BGB 3.000 28SEP19 - OLO67</securityDisplayLabel>
        </securityId>
        <weight>0.028389328</weight>    <== NEW VALUE
        <nominalAmount>0.01</nominalAmount>
        <componentPrice>0</componentPrice>
        <componentType>bond</componentType>
    </securityBasketComponent>
</securityBasketComponents>
<root>
    <securityBasketComponentNew>
        <label>2941</label>
        <securityId>AT0000386115</securityId>
        <weight>0.039597771</weight>
    </securityBasketComponentNew>
    <securityBasketComponentNew>
        <label>2862</label>
        <securityId>AT0000A0VRF9</securityId>
        <weight>0.020257355</weight>
    </securityBasketComponentNew>
    <securityBasketComponentNew>
        <label>2867</label>
        <securityId>BE0000318270</securityId>
        <weight>0.053516328</weight>
    </securityBasketComponentNew>
    <securityBasketComponentNew>
        <label>12897</label>
        <securityId>BE0000327362</securityId>
        <weight>0.028389328</weight>
    </securityBasketComponentNew>
    <securityBasketComponentNew>
        <label>4848</label>
        <securityId>FI4000010848</securityId>
        <weight>0.019722759</weight>
    </securityBasketComponentNew>
</root>
```

Thanks to all for the help and sorry for the long code written.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Where is your question?

Comment: @michael.hor257k My question is how can take the result with a xslt formula? I try to do it with 2 for-each nested but with no result.

Comment: Please show what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Please post your XSLT also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid your question is not very clear. It would also be much better to [minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the examples.

I am going to take a guess here and assume you want to replace the weight when there is a matching `securityBasketComponentNew` element, with the matching done by comparing `securityLabel` to `label`. If, so try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="new" match="securityBasketComponentNew" use="label" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="securityBasketComponent/weight[key('new', ../securityId/securityLabel)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('new', ../securityId/securityLabel)/weight" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:comment>NEW VALUE</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to the following **test input**:

```
<securityBasketDefinition>

    <securityBasketComponents>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityLabel>111</securityLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.111</weight>
        </securityBasketComponent>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityLabel>222</securityLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.222</weight>
        </securityBasketComponent>
        <securityBasketComponent>
            <securityId>
                <securityLabel>333</securityLabel>
            </securityId>
            <weight>0.333</weight>
        </securityBasketComponent>
    </securityBasketComponents>

    <root>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>111</label>
            <weight>1.11</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>333</label>
            <weight>3.33</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
        <securityBasketComponentNew>
            <label>444</label>
            <weight>4.44</weight>
        </securityBasketComponentNew>
    </root>

</securityBasketDefinition>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<securityBasketDefinition>
   <securityBasketComponents>
      <securityBasketComponent>
         <securityId>
            <securityLabel>111</securityLabel>
         </securityId>
         <weight>1.11</weight><!--NEW VALUE-->
      </securityBasketComponent>
      <securityBasketComponent>
         <securityId>
            <securityLabel>222</securityLabel>
         </securityId>
         <weight>0.222</weight>
      </securityBasketComponent>
      <securityBasketComponent>
         <securityId>
            <securityLabel>333</securityLabel>
         </securityId>
         <weight>3.33</weight><!--NEW VALUE-->
      </securityBasketComponent>
   </securityBasketComponents>
   <root>
      <securityBasketComponentNew>
         <label>111</label>
         <weight>1.11</weight>
      </securityBasketComponentNew>
      <securityBasketComponentNew>
         <label>333</label>
         <weight>3.33</weight>
      </securityBasketComponentNew>
      <securityBasketComponentNew>
         <label>444</label>
         <weight>4.44</weight>
      </securityBasketComponentNew>
   </root>
</securityBasketDefinition>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! But I can't understand what you do here: `<xsl:key name="new" match="securityBasketComponentNew" use="label" />`

Comment: @LuigiantonioCalo' See if this helps: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html